# When using urllib2, getting HTTPError 404

Tags: python, cookies, urllib2

So I'm using the following code:

```
allArgs = ['subway.py', '1b8d465e-b217-46f9-87a7-e9e48aaccb0f', 'B38']

HTTPCookieProcessor()

bus = urllib2.urlopen("http://api.prod.obanyc.com/api/siri/ \
    vehicle-monitoring.json?key=" + allArgs[1] + \
    "&VehicleMonitoringDetailLevel=calls&LineRef=" + allArgs[2])
```

and getting an HTTPError 404.  I tried reading other documentation and questions on various forums about this error, but I can't understand it.  Someone answering a similar question mentioned making a cookie opener, but again I don't really understand what that means.  I tried looking at examples of other people making cookie openers, but they all seemed to involve a lot of things that don't appear relevant to what I'm trying to do here, and I'm not sure exactly what it is that I need.

Help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
import urllib
import json

url = "http://api.prod.obanyc.com/api/siri/vehicle-monitoring.json?"

args = {'VehicleMonitoringDetailLevel': 'calls'}
args['key'] = '1b8d465e-b217-46f9-87a7-e9e48aaccb0f'
args['LineRef'] = 'B38'

try:
    data = json.load(urllib.urlopen('{}{}'.format(url, urllib.urlencode(args))))
except (IOError, ValueError):
    print('Problem fetching data')
```

Comment: Tried it and it gave me a "Problem fetching data" error.  Also, can urllib do more than urllib2?

Comment: Just noticed your edit, tried it out, and it worked.  Thank you very much!